# All variables are empty after include of wp-config

Tags: php, wordpress

I have simple PHP script that uses some data from wordpress config file. The problem is that all of the variables (that were declared before including of wp-config.php file) are empty.

```
<? 
$var1 = 100; 
$var2 = 100; 

include_once('wp-config.php');

echo "var1 + var2 = $var1 + $var2";

//var1 + var2 = 
?>
```

Comment: $var_total = $var1 + $var2; echo "var1 + var2 =".$var_total ;

Comment: do you get anything?

Comment: Where is your file currently located (ex: wp-content)?

Comment: wp-config.php file is included because i can use it's variables

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_unregister_GLOBALS()` is called within an included file of `wp-config.php`, it deletes all the global variables if `register_globals`is On. I could imagine, that depending on the WordPress version, it could also unset all the global variables, even if `register_globals` is off.

You could just declare your variables after you include the config file and I would really advise you to turn `register_globals` off if it is on.

Comment: Note that: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.